# Displaying XML info as is

Tags: php, xml, header, mime-types

I insert info into the database, its either text or a mixture of text and xml

I just want to display the xml as is, ignoring the tags but still printing them in text.

Here is an example of the xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<session sessioncode="6097926127">  
        <general>  
        <mode>real</mode>
            <gametype>Holdem NL $0.05/$0.10</gametype>  
          <tablename>Deferiet, 754781991</tablename>
          <tablecurrency>USD</tablecurrency>  
          <duration>N/A</duration>  
          <gamecount>N/A</gamecount>  
          <startdate>2013-08-08 19:50:48</startdate>  
          <currency>EUR</currency>  
          <nickname>johnnygogo</nickname>  
          <bets>N/A</bets>  
          <wins>N/A</wins>  
          <chipsin>N/A</chipsin>
                <chipsout>N/A</chipsout>
                <ipoints>N/A</ipoints>
            <statuspoints>N/A</statuspoints>
                <awardpoints>N/A</awardpoints>
                <is_asian>[is_asian]</is_asian>

    </general>  
    <game gamecode="5015773480">
     <general>
      <startdate>2013-08-08 19:51:50</startdate>          
      <players>
       <player seat="1" name="bigcity34" chips="$11.20" dealer="0" win="$0" bet="$0.05" rebuy="0" addon="0"/><player seat="3" name="joragruzin09999" chips="$3.70" dealer="0" win="$1.34" bet="$0.69" rebuy="0" addon="0"/><player seat="5" name="TMONEY123" chips="$11.55" dealer="0" win="$0" bet="$0" rebuy="0" addon="0"/><player seat="6" name="johnygogo" chips="$10" dealer="0" win="$0" bet="$0.69" rebuy="0" addon="0"/><player seat="8" name="13921" chips="$12.83" dealer="1" win="$0" bet="$0" rebuy="0" addon="0"/>
      </players>
     </general>
     <round no="0">
 <action no="1" player="bigcity34" type="1" sum="$0.05" cards="[cards]"/><action no="2" player="joragruzin09999" type="2" sum="$0.10" cards="[cards]"/><action no="3" player="johnnygogo" type="2" sum="$0.10" cards="[cards]"/>
</round>
    </game></session>
```

So i want it to look exactly like above in text format.

The code for displayng it is simply echoing out the field in the database where i can confirm it does store all the tags and is in original format.

```
echo = $row['body'];
```

Would have thought this is a common enough issue but after a lot of googling i cannot find a solution, im guessing im using a bad search term or too general of  search term cause it most be common.

Just to clarify, it can be just plain text or even formatted text like above that stackoverflow converts, it doesnt matter but right now it just displays something like this which is bad:

```
real
Holdem NL $0.05/$0.10 
Island Park, 754849081
USD 
N/A 
N/A 
2013-08-08 19:15:07 
EUR 
johnnygogo 
N/A 
N/A 
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
[is_asian]




2013-08-08 19:17:28 








X XX XX XX XX XD7 H10


S5 HA S8
```

Comment: echo htmlentities($row['body']);

Comment: echo nl2br(htmlentities($row['body']));

Comment: Indeed that did the trick, although i had to add a bit more

$email_log = nl2br(htmlentities($row['email_body']));
   $email_log_stripped = str_replace('&lt;br /&gt;', '', $email_log);

feel free to suggest that answer since this was the closest to the fix i could find and i will select it

Answer (score 2):

if you are just wanting to view it in-browser without it getting parsed or auto-downloaded, do this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $row['body'];
```

Comment: That didnt work, i assume its still stripping out all the tags, there was this in header. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

which i removed first and added your header line directly above the echo, that didnt work so i removed the header line and changed the header part to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8" /> and it still didnt work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to print your output simply in "pre" or "code" tags!

```
<pre>
<?php echo $row['body'];?>
</pre>
```